# How to convert integer to bit string in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How do I convert an unsigned integer to a binary string in Amazon Redshift? For example for a number 10 I would like to get "1010".

I found [a UDF that does this](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-udfs/blob/master/scalar-udfs/f_bitwise_to_string.sql) but I would rather not use any UDFs.

Comment: You could just... use the code in the definition of the udf that you linked to...

Comment: @Siyual But it's in Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that somebody has written this UDF indicates that there is no in-built capability within Redshift's SQL that can perform this operation.

If you do not want to use UDFs, you could create a lookup table with all binary values and then JOIN to it. This could be faster than running the Python function repeatedly, but I note that the function is coded as `STABLE`, so it will cache results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did so. There are some ways to do it without the UDF, but they are long and hard to understand, eg. `SELECT (bit_col%2+(bit_col>>1)%2+(bit_col>>2)%2+(bit_col>>3)%2+(bit_col>>4)%2+(bit_col>>5)%2+(bit_col>>6)%2+(bit_col>>7)%2)::INT2`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be late but please try `FROM_VARBYTE`:

```sql
SELECT FROM_VARBYTE(10::VARBYTE, 'binary')

>>> 00000000000000000000000000001010
```

If you only need the `1010` part, try adding a type conversion at the end:

```sql
SELECT FROM_VARBYTE(10::VARBYTE, 'binary')::INT

>>> 1010
```

If you are concerned that the result is out of range for the default integer, then cast it to `BIGINT`:

```sql
SELECT FROM_VARBYTE(1023::VARBYTE, 'binary')::BIGINT

>>> 1111111111
```